# reverse sort for object type array

Tags: php, sorting

Is their any direct way (without using for or foreach loop) using which we can reverse sort object type of array. Reference content code is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Date] => 20170820
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Date] => 20170817
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Date] => 20170711
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Date] => 20170710
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `usort()` and use your own logic for sorting. This would put the oldest dates on top:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return $a->Date > $b->Date ? +1 : -1;
});
```

Or if you want the opposite order, swap +1/-1;

Comment: why not `krsort()` or `rsort()` @this.lau_ ?

Comment: From the look of it he has an array of objects and wants to sort by an arbitrary property, so that wouldn't work with krsort or rsort (which sort by key or index).

Comment: he said he wants to reverse sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `krsort($array)` to sort array in reverse order with respect to keys.
Use  `rsort($array)`to sort array in reverse order with respect to values.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, This will help you sure

```
//Example with array $a
$a = array(array('date'=>20170820),array('date'=>20170817),array('date'=>20170711),array('date'=>20170710));
$a = json_decode(json_encode($a));

usort($a, function($x,$y){ return $x->date - $y->date; });
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
array_multisort($array,SORT_DESC,array_map(function ($v) { return $v->date; },$array));
```

Example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21b33f4d8b2bfb80fb02750693539b19060b5c86